# Dropdown content with rotating arrow (css/js)

Tags: javascript, css, rotation, dropdown

I'm stuck with my dropdown content. Trying to rotate arrows next to the clicked Button Titles. The first content is opened by default, so that arrow should be turned there by default.

- The current code does not turn Content 1 arrow by default and
- Click rotates all arrows as I don't know how to refer correctly to
  current icon in JS.

Any advices are very welcome.

```
  let dropdownModule = { 
   init: function(){
    this.cacheDom();
    this.bindEvents();
   },
   cacheDom: function(){
    this.$el = $('.dropdown-container');
    this.$dropdownBox = this.$el.find('.dropdown-box');
    this.$dropdownContent = this.$el.find('.dropdown-content');
    
   },
   bindEvents:function(){
    this.$dropdownBox.on('click', function(){
      
      let currentContent = $(this).next('.dropdown-content'); 
      currentContent.slideToggle(600);
      
      $('.dropdown-content').not(currentContent).slideUp(600);
      $('.fa-sort-down').toggleClass('r180');

    })
    }} 
    dropdownModule.init();
```

```
        
       <div class="dropdown-container">
       <div class="dropdown-box">Button Title 1<i class="fas fa-sort-down"></i>
       </div>
       <div style="display: block;" class="dropdown-content">
       Content 1
       </div>
       </div>
    
       <div class="dropdown-container">
       <div class="dropdown-box">Button Title 2<i class="fas fa-sort-down"></i>
       </div>
       <div class="dropdown-content">
       Content 2
       </div>
       </div>
```

```
     .fa-sort-down {
       transition: all 0.5s ease;
     }
     .r180 {
       transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, when you click on the dropdown it might be the  tag getting clicked and you need to find the target first.

Change your js to:

```
let dropdownModule = { 
   init: function(){
    this.cacheDom();
    this.bindEvents();
   },
   cacheDom: function(){
    this.$el = $('.dropdown-container');
    this.$dropdownBox = this.$el.find('.dropdown-box');
    this.$dropdownContent = this.$el.find('.dropdown-content');
    
   },
   bindEvents:function(){
    this.$dropdownBox.on('click', function(e){
      let target = $(e.target);
      if(!$(e.target).hasClass("dropdown-box")){
        target = $(e.target).parent();
      }
      $('.fa-sort-down').removeClass('r180');
      let currentContent = target.next('.dropdown-content'); 
      currentContent.slideToggle(600);
      
      $('.dropdown-content').not(currentContent).slideUp(600);
      target.find('.fa-sort-down').toggleClass('r180');

    })
    }} 
    dropdownModule.init();
```

Comment: Is it possible to turn the arrow of the closing box at the same time?